# Which and how many parameters define a macrostate of a physical system

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics

Just got an introduction to statistical mechanics in my thermodynamics class. I understand the concept of macrostates and microstates as the following:

A macrostate is some kind of restriction on all the possible microstates making a finite set of microstates that follow that restriction.

My question is on how free I am to choose that restriction. Many examples use N,V and E (number of particles, volume, and energy) as parameters to restrict the microstates but nothing keeps me from choosing any kind of restriction like mass, temperature, pressure and even simpler ones like the number of particles in a specific state or the ratio of different particles, in fact, I could use any number of parameters as I wish at the same time. I don't know if it is right for the macrostate of a system to be not unique because the concept of entropy would depend on what I'm using to define that macrostate. Let me know if there is something I got wrong. Thanks.

Comment: [Related](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/296103/do-the-results-of-statistical-mechanics-depend-upon-the-choice-of-macrostates)